# Why cURL does not finish his work after first successful request?

Tags: linux, curl

I have a licensing server which should return the customers' license information. Imagine this server is A, and I request the information from server B and C.  To do this, I run the command below on these Linux servers:

```
curl https://lic.website.com
```

The output is like this:

```
License No.: 123
Customer's URL: www.site.com
```

But receiving this response differs from server B and C. When I send requests from server C, I receive responses without any problem even if I send the requests every 1 seconds. (This is similar to entering `https://lic.website.com` in browser). But on the server B, I might receive 1 or 2 responses, but after sending the next requests, it stops returning responses. When I check the `top` command in Linux, I see the CURL request is kept in the processes list. I have checked the CPU and memory usage and there is not any issue on them. In addition, I have whitelisted all IPs in the licensing server.

May you help me to solve this issue please? If you need any further information, please let me know.

Update 1:
I've checked the command with `-v` argument. When everything is OK on server B the result is like this:

```
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
...
```

But when it stops working, the output is like this:

```
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
```

And after that everything goes to wait. I also have checked this command:

```
curl -v --tlsv1.2 --tls-max 1.2 ...
```

But the result were the same.

Comment: Well, how are the setups in servers B and C different? I think your question requires more information

Comment: What state is A in when this happens? B? What errors are logged?  What code is serving the licenses?

Comment: It seems like you maybe have a network issue, try running `traceroute lic.website.com`to see if the route is the same from the 2 servers.

Comment: Server B is an Ubuntu 20 with PHP 8.x, and server C is CentOS 7 with PHP 7.4. Other features are the same.

Comment: Please pay attention to Update 1 in my question.

Comment: What do the server logs say?